# Google webmaster tool Severe health issues are found in your property

Tags: google, robots.txt

I'm getting this message in GWT : Severe health issues are found in your property , Some important page is blocked by robots.txt.

My robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/

Sitemap: http://example.org/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Sharing the site URL will help the community of Pro Webmasters resolve your issue.

Comment: Agreed. There is not enough information here to even guess. It would help us to see your site. Are you linking to your admin section of WP on your site?? I do not know WP. Is there a link to the admin section for new installs that you should remove?

Comment: I may be off by a long shot saying this, but I'm gonna take a wild guess that most of your website contains links to pages within the /wp-admin folder.

Comment: Just remove that wp-admin lines, it is completely unnecessary, and you're blocking some of [your website parts](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Files) from Googlebot. Google well never crawl such thing when it is not linked from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Having maintained a number of wordpress sites I have found that in a great many sites the link to the admin page exists in the footer to make it easier to get to. The reason for this error is that Google has detected one or more links on your indexable pages to the wordpress admin pages and when it tries to go there it detects that it is blocked. The error is shown in case the block was an accident to give you the chance to be able to fix it and enable crawling of that page. The only options really are to...

- Ignore the warning (not a big issue as you don't want the admin page crawled)
- Remove the link from the page and memorise it for accessing the admin page
- Add a `rel=nofollow` tag to all instances of the link so that Google doesn't try to crawl that page anymore

Not a big issue whichever option is taken as because all would be valid and non will cause you any issues. Furthermore having an error like this will not affect your SERP rank as Google will simply not index the page and so the page will not affect the rank of any backlinked pages.